# Is there a problem with my proof?

Tags: real-analysis, limits

I'm trying to prove this theorem:

---

Let $a_n$ and $c_n$ be sequences of real numbers such that $a_n$ converges to $0$, and $c_na_n^2$ converges to $0$. Then

$$ \lim\limits_{n\rightarrow \infty}(1 + a_n)^{c_n}e^{-a_nc_n} = 1 $$

---

I do it in the following way:

$$
\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow \infty}(1 + a_n)^{c_n}e^{-a_nc_n} = \lim\limits_{n\rightarrow \infty}(1 + a_n)^{c_na_n/a_n}e^{-a_nc_n} = \lim\limits_{n\rightarrow \infty}e^{a_nc_n}e^{-a_nc_n} = 1
$$

So, the question is where I need "$c_na_n^2$ converges to 0" condition. Maybe I should have "$c_na_n$ converges to 0" condition so that I can do this:
$$
\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow \infty}(1 + a_n)^{c_na_n/a_n} = \lim\limits_{n\rightarrow \infty}e^{a_nc_n}
$$

but I totally don't see why I need "$c_na_n^2$ converges to 0."

Comment: hint: Write  $(1+a_n)^{c_n}$   using exp and log and then taylor expand $\log(1+a_n)$

Comment: What is your justification for claiming  $$\lim_{n\to\infty}{c_aa_n/a_n} = \lim_{n\to\infty} e^{a_nc_n}?$$ Why do think you can take the limit of part of the expression as $n \to \infty$, but also leave other parts of the expression depending on $n$ constant, so you can that limit separately?

Comment: I suggest first coming up with a proof that $\lim_{n\to\infty}(1+a_n)^{1/a_n}=e$. (This is not true for all $a_n\to 0$, so you have to be careful.) Then, see if you can adapt that proof to the current problem.